# Ошибка "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" при передачи данных в event laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel-5.7

Имеется следующий код в контроллере Laravel

```
$result = Message::create($request->all());
event(new \App\Events\StrangeEvent($result));
```

При передаче любого значения в event всегда появляется данная ошибка. Каким образом это исправить?

Comment: Charset какой у таблицы? Или в конфиге базы прописан, возможно, какой?

Comment: utf8mb4. Вряд ли проблема именно в этом, потому что даже при передаче строкового значения выходит ошибка